# COUNTIF in Power BI (New calculated column Required)

Tags: powerbi, dax, countif

I want to calculate the running count of each value based on column A. In Excel, I am applying the following formula

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)
```

I would like to get the same result in Power BI. Can you please advise.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible for you to do it using VBA?

Comment: Also you could use PivotTable like this example https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2004-excel-count-by-group.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just a single column, this is impossible in DAX because duplicated rows cannot be distinguished as there is no inherent order to a column.

However, if you have an index column on the table (you can easily add one in the Query Editor), then it is possible to define such a calculated column so that it works similarly to the Excel formula.

```
CountIf =
VAR CurrentIndex = DATA[Index]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( DATA ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( DATA, DATA[ITEM] ),
        DATA[Index] <= CurrentIndex
    )
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your solutions. I will follow up your advise.